# Finding closest street name from point using MMQGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, mmqgis

I got a list of points spread over a city and their coordinates. I'd like to find out the name of the closest address (or at least street) from each point. I downloaded the plugin MMQGIS which allow to geocode address from coordinate but not the inverse.

Does anyone know a solution to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

In ArcGIS, the tool would be Near (or Near Table). Based on [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168120/what-qgis-tool-or-plugin-is-equivalent-to-the-esri-near-tool), I think the QGIS equivalent is NNJoin. What roads layer are you using? You could download the TIGER roads from the US Census for free here: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html (assuming you are looking at a US city).

If you'd prefer an API option, check out the Google Maps Nearest Roads API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest