# Finding closest point on line from point using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity, points-to-line, arcgis-10.8

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

How can I find the point on a line that is closest to a given point, or alternatively, the closest vertex point of the line if it is not perpendicular?

Refer to the following images for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tool you want is the near tool.  [See this link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm). Sadly this tool only works with an advanced ArcGIS license. If you do not have an advanced license [I see this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168120/what-qgis-tool-or-plugin-is-equivalent-to-the-esri-near-tool) presents an alternative using free QGIS tools.

Answer (score 0):

As an ArcMap user you are likely to be entitled to ArcGIS Pro licensing where the [Near (Analysis)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool is what I would explore first to try to meet these requirements.

That tool:

> Calculates distance and additional proximity information between the
> input features and the closest feature in another layer or feature
> class.

It is available at all ArcGIS Pro licensing levels.